# Set up veth-pair OpenWrt

Tags: networking, router

[interfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ALpj.png)

[vlan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4fBS.png)

I am trying to set up sqm for my wan in default OpenWrt on a Linksys3200acm, it is bridged to a Asus-dsl rt86u modem. I have installed k-modveth, ipfull, and app-luci-sqm on OpenWrt.

Incoming WAN traffic will forward to veth0

Incoming WAN traffic to destination LAN will forward to veth0

I have attempted to set it up with the following:

add veth1 to br-lan bridge

sqm egress veth0, sqm ingress veth1

apply these rules

```
ip link add type veth
ip link set up veth0
ip link set up veth1
ip link set veth1 master br-lan

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1.2 -o veth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s -i eth1.2 -d br-lan -o veth0 -j ACCEPT
```

This is not functional. I need a step by step guide for setting up a veth pair for OpenWrt.

Comment: Veth-pairs are normally used to connect network namespaces. Have both endpoints of a veth-pair in the same namespace doesn't make a lot of sense. I am not familiar with sqm, but it looks like a wrapper around tc, so I'd assume it works directly on the physical interface (I assume the WAN interface in your case). So why do you think you need veth-pairs? How do you expect this to work?

Comment: WAN interface, in traffic forward to veth0

LAN Interface, wan destination traffic forward to veth0

Veth0, sqm egress

Veth1, bridged to LAN, sqm egress

My intention is to sqm the veth-pair ingress/egress. I'm assuming the code will be written with ip rules but I do not know how to configure this.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand why you think you need veth-pairs. From reading the sqm documentation, I'd assume it will just apply `tc` on the physical outgoing interface (WAN, whatever the physical interface in your setup is). This "squeeze it forcefully through a veth-pair and then apply sqm setup" makes no sense to me at all. Where did you read that you need a veth-pair for that?

Comment: I am trying to mark with dscp in and out of the veth and apply sqm on the veth. I am not familiar with tc commands, would you provide a script?

Comment: You don't "mark with dscp in and out of the veth", that's not how it works. You use dscp in the appropriate iptables chain, whatever it is for your use case. No, I can't supply a tc script, that's what sqm is supposed to do. Please edit your qestion and describe your actual goal, this looks like an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where your Y is "I need veth-pairs with sqm".